# python string strip not working for the trailing double quote

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to do a task automatically using python script but met with this strange phenomenon. I looked for the same in SO but it's slightly different, so I ask here using simplified example.
I have a file called test1.txt below.

```
"https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7286-efficient-algorithms-for-non-convex-isotonic-regression-through-submodular-optimization" ## Efficient Algorithms for Non-convex Isotonic Regression through Submodular Optimization
"https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7287-structure-aware-convolutional-neural-networks" ## Structure-Aware Convolutional Neural Networks
"https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7288-kalman-normalization-normalizing-internal-representations-across-network-layers" ## Kalman Normalization: Normalizing Internal Representations Across Network Layers
"https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7289-hogwild-gibbs-can-be-panaccurate" ## HOGWILD!-Gibbs can be PanAccurate
```

and the python script quest.py

```
import re

with open('test1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        #print line
        link = re.sub(" ##.*","",line)
        print link
        link1 = link.strip('\"')
        print link1
```

When I execute it by `python quest.py`, I get

```
"https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7286-efficient-algorithms-for-non-convex-isotonic-regression-through-submodular-optimization"

https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7286-efficient-algorithms-for-non-convex-isotonic-regression-through-submodular-optimization"

"https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7287-structure-aware-convolutional-neural-networks"

https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7287-structure-aware-convolutional-neural-networks"

"https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7288-kalman-normalization-normalizing-internal-representations-across-network-layers"

https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7288-kalman-normalization-normalizing-internal-representations-across-network-layers"

"https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7289-hogwild-gibbs-can-be-panaccurate"

https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7289-hogwild-gibbs-can-be-panaccurate"
```

I want to print the link first time with the surrounding double quotes(=link) and then without the double quotes(=link1). But why do I see the trailing double quote for the link1?

Comment: Probably your string doesn’t end with double quote, but with newline char. You need to strip that too. Try: link.strip(‘“\n’)

Comment: `Python2` I guess?

Comment: @randomir Ah, tat was correct. I don't know why there was new line(\n). Thanks. make it an answer, I'll select it!

Comment: Just replace the double quotes with an empty string, check my answer below @ChanKim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's [`str.strip([chars])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) will remove leading and trailing `chars`, but will stop once it reaches a character not in `chars`.

Looks like your `link` ends with a newline char, and stripping stops before even reaching the double quote. (Hint: `print` adds only one newline, and in your output you have two.)

To strip double quotes and newline chars:

```
link1 = link.strip('"\n')
```

Also, it's worth mentioning (as @glibdud notes in comments), the reason links were ending with a newline was because file iterator doesn't strip newlines, neither does the `sub` expression (because `.` doesn't include the newline; to include it, add [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) regex flag).

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that the reason the links end in newlines is because looping over lines of a file includes the newlines, and `.` by default will not match newlines in a regex, so they're not included in the `sub()`.

Comment: Thanks!(I suspect something like that when I saw the added void lines but didn't know it exactly).

Comment: @glibdud Thank you! That was a good point! (the loop adding '\n')

Comment: @ChanKim, happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Just strip the double quotes and newline when you want to print without quotes, and only strip newlines, when you want to print with double quotes

```
import re

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip():
            #print line
            link = re.sub(" ##.*", "", line)
            #Print with double quotes
            print link.strip('\n')
            #Print without double quotes by replacing double quotes with empty char
            print link.strip('"\n')

            #Print without double quotes by removing double quotes entirely
            #print link.strip("\"")
```

The output will then be

```
"https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7286-efficient-algorithms-for-non-convex-isotonic-regression-through-submodular-optimization"
https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7286-efficient-algorithms-for-non-convex-isotonic-regression-through-submodular-optimization
"https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7287-structure-aware-convolutional-neural-networks"
https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7287-structure-aware-convolutional-neural-networks
"https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7288-kalman-normalization-normalizing-internal-representations-across-network-layers"
https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7288-kalman-normalization-normalizing-internal-representations-across-network-layers
"https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7289-hogwild-gibbs-can-be-panaccurate"
https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7289-hogwild-gibbs-can-be-panaccurate
```

Comment: Corrected both issues @glibdud, thanks for the suggestion, please upvote if it looks good now